# For subprocess.stderr=STDOUT - Is stdout=PIPE better than stdout="a_file_name"?

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, popen, stderr

**[EDITED]**
2 options for handling standard output from `subprocess.Popen` are `stdout="a_file_name"` and `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`.
`stderr` can be combined with either of those via `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`.

For what I'm currently doing (fuzz-testing), my resulting `stdout="a_file_name"` code is slightly shorter and cleaner.

However, from what I’ve seen, it seems that `stdout=PIPE` is often preferred by others, but I’m not sure of all of the reasons why.

**If the `cmd` used in `Popen([cmd, arg], ...)` is an external executable which writes error output to `stderr`, is `stdout=PIPE` somehow better than `stdout="a_file_name"`?**

**What are some pros and cons of each?**

- In my particular context (see code snippets below), 1 advantage I can see to using `stdout=PIPE` rather than `stdout="a_file_name"` is that the former would let me easily skip writing an empty file.
- In the event of a `cmd` crash, might 1 of the 2 somehow be more likely to get all of the error output?

Although I have my particular context in mind, I'd be interested in knowing the answer(s) for the more general case as well.

To better explain my context, here are my 2 alternative code segments:

```
import subprocess
import sys

assert sys.version_info >= (3, 3)
    # timeout added for subprocess's wait() and communicate() in Python 3.3.

with open('sub_proc1.outerr', 'w') as f_outerr1:
    sub_proc1 = subprocess.Popen([cmd, args], stdout=f_outerr1,
                                 stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                                 universal_newlines=True)
    try:
        return_code = sub_proc1.wait(timeout=10)
        print('*** %s CRASHED with return code: %d.' % (cmd, return_code))
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        print('*** %s succeeded.' % cmd)
        sub_proc1.kill()
```

versus:

```
...
with open('sub_proc2.outerr', 'w') as f_outerr2:
    sub_proc2 = subprocess.Popen([cmd, args], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                 stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                                 universal_newlines=True)
    try:
        (sub_proc2_out, sub_proc2_err) = sub_proc2.communicate(timeout=10)
        print('*** %s CRASHED with return code: %d.' %
              (cmd, sub_proc2.poll()))
        assert sub_proc2_err is None
            # Since stderr was redirected to STDOUT, this should be None.
        f_outerr2.write(str(sub_proc2_out or ""))
            # Treat 'None' as an empty string).
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        print('*** %s succeeded.' % cmd)
        sub_proc2.kill()
```

ORIGINAL POST:

> TITLE: subprocess: Pros and cons of stderr=STDOUT vs. stderr=PIPE?
>
> The 2 principal alternatives for handling error output from
>   'subprocess.Popen' seem to be 'stderr=STDOUT' (with
>   'stdout="some_file"') and 'stderr=PIPE'.
>
> For what I want to do (fuzz-testing), my resulting 'stderr=STDOUT'
>   code is a little shorter and cleaner.
>
> However, from what I've read, it seems that 'stderr=PIPE' is
>   preferred, but I'm not sure of all of the reasons why.
>
> If the 'cmd' used is an external executable which writes error output
>   to 'stderr', what are the pros and cons of using 'stderr=STDOUT'
>   versus 'stderr=PIPE'?
>
> ...

Comment: I don't think there's much difference between the two codes if you're not doing anything with the output (other than writing to a file) in your testing program. If you wanted to examine the actual details of the output (e.g. to include it in your `print` calls, perhaps, or checking that it writes out a specific string), then using `PIPE` would be necessary. One possible advantage of the first code is that it will interleave the stdout and stderr streams for you if the program being run alternates writing to them. On the other hand, you can't tell the two outputs apart!

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comment, Blckknght.

I can see that the PIPE would be the better option if I wanted to examine the actual details of the output.

In my particular context, having the stdout and stderr streams interleaved is fine.

Comment: Your comment caused me to realize something which I hadn't realized previously.  

Such interleaving is possible with either method:  
    stdout="a_file_name", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT  
or  
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT    

Similarly, having the stdout and sterrr streams NON-interleaved is also possible with either method:
    stdout="file_name_1", stderr="file_name_2"
or  
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE

Comment: Accordingly, I've updated my post and its title to reflect the 2 interleaved options:

- NEW TITLE: For subprocess.stderr=STDOUT - Is stdout=PIPE better than stdout="a_file_name"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing to a specific file means that your program will have conflicts if it is run more than once at a time since both processes will want to write to the same file.  (search for issues with temporary file creation and security vulnerabilities)

Using a pipe means there is no issue of file name uniqueness.

Do you care about the output?  If not, then use `subprocess.DEVNULL` and it will discard the output for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer dsh.

I can see that writing to a specific file could cause name conflicts.
My script, though, writes all of its output in a subfolder based on the current date/time, so that shouldn't be a problem for it:


        `out_fdr = time.strftime(os.path.join('%Y', '%m', '%d', '%H.%M.%S'))`

I do care about the output.
I've gotten some helpful info from my .outerr files so far, such as:
Out of memory
or
Bogus memory allocation size

Comment: If it runs twice in the same second, you'll have a name collision on the directory :).  If you want to save the output for future use then a file is more appropriate.  If you want to process the output in your program then a pipe is more natural.

Comment: That's a BIG plus.
My PDF fuzz-testing typically finds a crash < 1% of the time, and a PIPE will let me only write a stderr output file if:
1. There is stderr output to be written.
AND
2. There is a crash.
[Originally, I had used stderr="a_file_name", and then deleted the file if either it was empty OR there was no crash.]
Thanks.